# comment not showing in post_detail

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I want to include comment to my detail but it is not showing. Here is the relevant part of my views.py

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                                status = 'published',
                                publish__year = year,
                                publish__month = month,
                                publish__day = day)
comments = post.comments.filter(active= True)
if request.method == 'POST':
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
        new_comment.post = post
        new_comment.save()
else:
    comment_form = CommentForm()
return render(request, 'detail.html', {'post':post})
```

Here is models.py file. I think the problem will be with my views file

```
class Comment(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
email = models.EmailField()
body = models.TextField()
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('created',)

def __str__(self):
    return 'comment by {} on {}'.format(self.name, self.post)
```

Here is my detail.html please notify me when you observe the error

```
{% with comments.count as total_comments %}
<h2>
{{ total_comments }} comment{{ total_comments|pluralize }}
</h2>
{% endwith %}
{% for comment in comments %}
<div class="comment">
<p class="info">
Comment {{ forloop.counter }} by {{ comment.name }}
{{ comment.created }}
</p>
{{ comment.body|linebreaks }}
</div>
{% empty %}
<p>There are no comments yet.</p>
{% endfor %}
{% if new_comment %}
<h2>Your comment has been added.</h2>
{% else %}
<h2>Add a new comment</h2>
<form action="." method="POST">
    {{ comment_form.as_p }}
{% csrf_token %}
<p><input type="submit" value="Add comment"></p>
</form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You don't add `comments` to your context.

Comment: sorry I did not get u

Comment: To be able to use variable `comments` in your template, you need to add it to context of `render()` method.
`return render(request, 'detail.html', context={'post':post, 'comments': comments})`

Comment: And you don't use `post` variable in your template, so why add it to context?

Comment: Thanks it worked